# No matching constructor for initialization of 'xxx'

Tags: c++

I want to implement a tcp server based on libevent, in which server_socket is responsible for establishing the connection, server_connect encapsulates the client connection as a class for handling read and write requests, but I need to **save the server_socket reference in the server_connect class**.

Declaration of this class:

```
class server_connect final {

public:
    explicit server_connect(server_socket &, int, event_base *);
    ...

private:
    server_socket &server_sock;
    ...

};
```

Save the server_connect object in the map in another function

```
typedef std::pair<int, server_connect> connect_pair;

// callback function for accept event
void tcp_accept_handler(int socket_fd, short events, void *arg) {
    auto server_sk_ptr = (server_socket*) arg;
    ...
    // When the code here calls the server_connect constructor, it prompts that the corresponding constructor cannot be found
    server_sk_ptr->connect_map.insert(connect_pair(client_sock_fd, server_connect(*server_sk_ptr, client_sock_fd, server_sk_ptr->ev_base)));
}
```

> I'm not very good at English so there may be some grammatical errors. thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Your code is missing context. Please post a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Perhaps the constructor that cannot be found is a copy constructor. There's probably something in `server_connect` that makes it non-copyable.

Comment: The full error message should be pasted (as text) into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I added the declaration of the class keyword before the first parameter of the constructor, which is server_socket, and then the compilation passed.

```
// before
explicit server_connect(server_socket &, int, event_base *);
// after
explicit server_connect(class server_socket &, int, event_base *);
```

but I don't know what the reason is